# Airflow Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-bigquery, google-drive-api, airflow, mwaa

I am trying to run a bigquery query on Airflow with MWAA.

This query uses a table that is based on a Google Sheet. When I run it, I have the following error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

I already have a working Google cloud connection on Airflow with an admin service account.

Also:

- This service account has access to the google sheet
- I added `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` in the scopes of the Airflow connection
- I re-generated a JSON file

Am I doing something wrong? Any idea what I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085437/bq-cli-not-getting-data-from-google-sheets

Comment: Mmmmm not really :/ The API is already enabled, and I already added the drive scope on airflow connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by creating a NEW Airflow connection. It's a new google cloud connection, with the exact same values as the default google_cloud_default values. Now it works perfectly.

Hope it can help !